# How [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) work together?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and I am learning Angular 6. I understood about ngModel. But while I was experimenting with ngModelChange, some questions raised.

I have an html element 
HTML

```
<input #input  type="text" [value]="name" [(ngModel)] ="name" (ngModelChange) ="change(input.value)"/>
```

Typescript

```
change(event :any) {
    this.name = event;
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

Upon changing the value in the input , I can see the changes with the name property.

When I changed the html code to

HTML

```
<input #input type="text" [value]="name"  [ngModel] ="name" 
(ngModelChange)="change(input.value)" />
{{ name }}
```

TS

```
change(event :any) {
    this.name = event;
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

It's working fine as expected in the console and in the UI.

Question 1

```
<input #input  type="text" [value]="name" [(ngModel)] ="name" 
(ngModelChange) ="change(input.value)"/>
```

&

```
<input #input type="text" [value]="name"  [ngModel] ="name" 
(ngModelChange)="change(input.value)" />
```

are same??

Question 2.

When I remove the [ngModel] directive. The ngModelChange is not getting triggered. Is it mandatory to have [ngModel]? If yes,Why?

HTML

```
<input #input type="text" [value]="name" 
(ngModelChange)="change(input.value)" />
<br/>
<br/>
{{ name }}
```

TS

```
change(event: any) {
     this.name = event;
     console.log(this.name);
 }
```

This would be a great help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

> The [()] syntax is easy to demonstrate when the element has a settable property called x and a corresponding event named xChange. Here's a SizerComponent that fits this pattern. It has a size value property and a companion sizeChange event

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#basics-of-two-way-binding

So, they are equivalent.

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="name"/>
<input [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange) ="name = $event"/>
```

But if there is no corresponding property, then `xChange` will not work.

```html
<input (ngModelChange) ="name = $event"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

**ad Question 1)**
They are not the same as you write it. 
Writing

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="change(input.value)"/>
```

does not make sense really if you just want to set the variables value,
because the (banana-in-a-box) expression `[(ngModel)]` itself is just syntactic sugar for

`[ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="name = $event"`

So your example would result in:

```html
<input [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="name = $event" (ngModelChange)="change(input.value)"/>
```

**ad Question 2)**
Yes you need at least the `[ngModel]="name"` expression to be able to activate the Angular directive. We can see that in the selector of the NgModel directive in the [Angular source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L132) itself:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])',
  providers: [formControlBinding],
  exportAs: 'ngModel'
})
export class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges,
    OnDestroy {
    ...
    ...
    @Output('ngModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();
    ...
```

Comment: ```<input [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="doSomethingElse($event)"/>```
I think this syntax is needed if you want to update values, as well as to perform some other action on change. like find in other array.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add on the previous answers that mixing `[(ngModel)]` (banana in a box) and `(ngModelChange)` can have a use case, because `(ngModelChange)` will still be fired after the banana in a box updated your model.

For example, if for some reason you want to trigger a `nameChange` EventEmitter every time the name is changed you could write it this way

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="nameChange.emit(name)" />
```

Quick stackblitz to demonstrate that the model is already updated when `(ngModelChange)` is fired : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-teu1am