# How supply string as input for Ngbdatepicker in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, ngb-datepicker

We are using ngbDatePicker in our application. From backend getting date as a string
and ngbDatePicker work with **{year: Value, month: Value, day: Value}**.

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" 
          placeholder="yy/mm/dd" 
          [(ngModel)]="registerDate" 
          ngbDatepicker
          #d="ngbDatepicker" >
          <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </button>
    </div>
```

Here **registerDate** value coming as string.

its not reading string formate how come i make it readble by ngbDatepicker.

Comment: What does the date string from back end look like?

Comment: its "MM/DD/YY" in this formate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you splitting up your `[(ngModel)]` into two parts (See here [How [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901940/how-ngmodel-and-ngmodelchange-work-together)).

Then you could do something like this:

```
<input class="form-control" 
       placeholder="yy/mm/dd" 

       [ngModel]="getDateAsObject()"
       (ngModelChange)="writeDateToString($event)"

       ngbDatepicker
       #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

---

Or you could just temporarily save it in the given format and only transform it to string when needed. Then you could stick to `[(ngModel)]`... and it would also be more performant.